# Redirect angular route with trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

Requirements:

```
/month      Redirect to /month/1   (january is the default month)
/month/     Redirect to /month/1
/month/4    No redirect, show april
```

My best attempt:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/month/:monthNo', {
    templateUrl: 'views/month.html',
    controller: 'MonthCtrl'
  })
```

This works:

```
  .when('/month', {
    redirectTo: '/month/1'  // default redirect to january
  })
```

This doesn't (notice trialing slash: **/month/**):

```
  .when('/month/', {
    redirectTo: '/month/1' 
  })
```

The `/month/` matches `.when('/month/:monthNo'...` so is something like this possible:

```
  .when('/month/:monthNo', {
    runThisCodeFirst: function() { if(!monthNo) redirectTo: '/month/1'}
    templateUrl: 'views/month.html',
    controller: 'MonthCtrl'
  })
```

Or are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that you just make the .when calls in the wrong order? They are chained, so the first matching .when will end the processing. It works if I do it like this:

```
.when('/month', {
  redirectTo: '/month/1'
})
.when('/month/:monthNo', {
  template: 'This!'
})
```

However if I do it like this, I see the problem you are describing:

```
.when('/month/:monthNo', {
  template: 'This!'
})
.when('/month', {
  redirectTo: '/month/1'
})
```

So apparently '/month' also matches '/month/'. But so does '/month/:monthNo', therefore you want to have the redirecting rule first.